# Can events be used in a multi-threaded application safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

In the following code I have two classes, one that runs in a separate thread and fires events, the other that subscribes to this event and receives data from the event. The event code I have based off of Jon Skeet's article http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

In this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37474/Threadsafe-Events it says...

> For this reason, I recommend the same approach that Jon Skeet ends up recommending at the end of Delegates and Events: "don't do that", i.e., don't use events in a multithreaded fashion. If an event exists on an object, then only one thread should be able to subscribe to or unsubscribe from that event, and it's the same thread that will raise the event.

Now obviously my design breaks that, in that it fires the event on a different thread to that it was subscribed on. How could I modify my design so that it adhears to the principle of not using events in a multi-threaded fashion or is this not possible ?

The other way I thought of doing it was just to pass in my callback method as a delegate into class B and call that instead of calling the event?

I may have completely the wrong end of the stick, so any clarification would be appreciated.

Note: I am aware that .Net 4.0 has apparently solved this issue, however I would still be interested in if there is a way to do it pre .Net 4

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int a);

class A
{
    void main()
    {
        B bObject = new B();
        bObject.MyEvent += new MyDelegate(NiceMethod);
        bObject.Run();
    }   

    void NiceMethod(int a)
    {   
        Console.Writeline({0}, a);  
    }
}

class B
{
    readonly object eventLock = new object();

    MyDelegate myDel;

    public event MyDelegate MyEvent
    {   
        add
        {
            lock (eventLock)
            {
                myDel += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (eventLock)
            {
                myDel -= value;
            }
        }
    }   

    //Assume this runs in a new thread and calls back data using MyEvent
    //Have ommited thread code for simplicity
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MyDelegate handler;
            lock (someEventLock)
            {
                handler = myDel;
            }
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler (i);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The c# compiler has *always* added thread-safety to field-like events (I.e. where the compiler writes the add/remove for you) - the implementation for that has been improved in c# 4. Also, this isn't a .net 4 thing - it is a c# 4 thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong about raising events or listening to events from different threads. It is the responsibility of the listener to deal with being invoked from another thread. As Marc Gravell notes in his comment, adding and removing of listeners to and from events from different threads is (and always has been) supported by the compiler generated `add` and `remove` implementations. The only problem is to raise the event in a thread safe fashion, which can be done by synchronizing the access to event via the same kind of spinlock the generated `add` and `remove` are using:

```
class B 
{  
    public event MyDelegate MyEvent;

    protected OnMyEvent(int p_Arg)
    {
        // Delegates are immutable and add/remove default
        // implementations always generate a new instance of the 
        // delegate. Therefore, tTmp (if not null) can be safely invoked
        var tTmp = 
            System.Threading.Interlocked
            .CompareExchange(ref MyEvent, null, null);
        if (tTmp != null) {
            tTmp(p_Arg);
        }
    }

    //Assume this runs in a new thread and calls back data using MyEvent 
    //Have ommited thread code for simplicity 
    public void Run() 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        { 
            OnMyEvent(i);
        }    
    } 
}
```

The only thing that could happen is that the listener is invoked **after** it has been removed from the event list. IMHO, the listener must be able to deal with this situation as it deals with beeing invoked from separate threads...

Comment: Adding and removing handlers from different threads has not always been *correctly* supported by C# compilers.  Older C# compilers would generate code which was not at all thread-safe for classes which subscribed to their own events, and which would lock on `this` when adding/removing other objects' events.

Comment: I think the change was between C# 3 and C# 4.  What makes the situation with older compilers really horrible is that if a class had an event named `Foo`, then outside the class, `thing.Foo += bar` would call the `AddHandler` method (which would lock on `thing`), but within the class, `Foo += bar` would regard `Foo` as the name of a private delegate, and interpret the statement as `Foo = Foo + bar;` with no locking.  The net effect is that the code pretends to be thread-safe, but if a class uses its events internally the code really isn't thread-safe at all.

Comment: Personally, I think that defining an event named `Foo` should never have defined a delegate named `Foo`; instead, the delegate should have had some other name (e.g. `Foo__event`), and an attempt to "invoke" an event should have been translated into a call to a method with a different name (e.g. `Foo__raiseevent`), which could then act on the delegate as appropriate.